# Saving state of the view when switching from portrait to landscape

Tags: android, orientation, savestate

I have created a simple calendar using `GridView` and whenever I switch from portrait view to landscape (or back) it doesn't preserve the state. For example, I change to January in portrait view and in landscape it is back to December. I tried to fix that and added this code to my `OnCreate()`:

```
    if(savedInstanceState != null && savedInstanceState.containsKey(CALENDAR)){
        mCalendar = (Calendar) savedInstanceState.getSerializable(CALENDAR);
   }else{
    mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
   }
```

And added this method to the class:

```
@Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        //Save the calendar instance in case the user changed it
        outState.putSerializable(CALENDAR, mCalendar);
    }
```

Unfortunately it doesn't want to work, and the months still keep switching to initial one, when changing phone orientation. Can someone please help me?

---

Code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_calendar);

    mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
    month = mCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
    year = mCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    previous = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_prevMonth);
    next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_nextMonth);
    displayMonth = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.et_displayMonth);
    gv_daysOfWeek = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gv_daysOfWeek);
    gv_calendar = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gv_calendar);

    previous.setOnClickListener(this);
    next.setOnClickListener(this);
    displayMonth.setText(DateFormat.format(monthDisplay, mCalendar.getTime()));

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.weekdays_grid, R.id.grid_item_label, WEEK_DAYS);
    gv_daysOfWeek.setAdapter(adapter);

    setGridCellAdapter(month, year);

    if(savedInstanceState != null && savedInstanceState.containsKey(CALENDAR)){
        mCalendar = (Calendar) savedInstanceState.getSerializable(CALENDAR);
    }else{
        mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    }
}

/**
 * Method responsible for intialising the adapter
 */
 private void setGridCellAdapter(int month, int year) {
     cellAdapter = new GridCellAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.id.day_gridcell, month, year);
     mCalendar.set(year, month - 1 , mCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
     displayMonth.setText(DateFormat.format(monthDisplay, mCalendar.getTime()));
     cellAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
     gv_calendar.setAdapter(cellAdapter);
 }
```

Comment: Post more code.. We have no idea how you are using mCalendar

Comment: Is this in a Fragment or Activity?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/FXR2jpGY here is more code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not reading your saved state until *after* you have set up the GridView... Change you code around to read the saved stated *first*:

```
if(savedInstanceState != null && savedInstanceState.containsKey(CALENDAR)){
    mCalendar = (Calendar) savedInstanceState.getSerializable(CALENDAR);
}else{
    mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
}
month = mCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
year = mCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);

// Initialize your Buttons and such...

setGridCellAdapter(month, year);
```

Remove any other code that tries to set `mCalendar` in `onCreate()`.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
mCalendar.set(year, month - 1 , 1);
```

Suggestion: If you use Month as the save and recover object instead of calender will be more simple.